# Identifying an extra NMR peak in silyl protection reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I protected a phenol with the TIPSCl/triethylamine procedure. The product was isolated by column (hexanes/EtOAc) and shows an extra singlet at 1.05 ppm in $\ce{CDCl3}$, integrating to ~10 H. Whatever this is I cannot find in under UV or various TLC stains ($\ce{KMnO4}$, vanilin, PMA). The integration of the peak goes smaller after one more column. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a corresponding bonus peak in the 13C?

Comment: Found two extra peaks in the aliphatic region, 18.1, 17.8, 14.6, 14.2,12.4. I know two of these are the isopropyl and a CH3 from an ethyl, did not assign them though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe some of your triisopropylsilyl chloride may be hydrolyzed triisopropylsilylol, $\ce{((CH3)2CH)3SiOH}$. That may gives you $\delta$ 1.04 and 12.4 (for $\ce{C}$ attached to $\ce{Si}$) in $\mathrm{^1H}$- and $\mathrm{^{13}C}$-NMR spectra, respectively. Compare the spectral values in Ref.1 and 2 (see below; corresponding $\ce{^{13}C}$ values are in red):

[image: Spectral Data]

**References:**

1. A. Goti, M. Cacciarini, F. Cardona, A. Brandi, “A convenient access to (*3S*)-3-(triisopropylsilyl)oxy-1-pyrroline *N*-oxide, a useful intermediate for polyfunctionalized enantiopure indolizidine and pyrrolizidine synthesis,” *Tetrahedron Letters* **1999**, *40(14)*, 2853–2856 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(99)00310-X).
2. R. F. Cunico, L. Bedell, “The triisopropylsilyl group as a hydroxyl-protecting function,” *J. Org. Chem.* **1980**, *45(23)*, 4797–4798 (https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01311a058).

Comment: This is what I'd originally thought (usually stuff like R3SiOH or R3SiOSiR3 are byproducts from silyl protection). What stopped me from putting it forward was the multiplicity, as the big peak for TIPS should be a doublet.

Comment: yes the singlet is what confuses me -- it looks like some other silylanes, maybe my TIPSCl have some TMS or TBDMS with it?

Comment: Take an NMR of TIPSCl.

Comment: @user55119: Good point. Even better, take another NMR with hydrolyzed TIP-Cl, if you are curious to know the by product.

Comment: @orthocresol: I agreed with you completely. Yet, both of sighted references reported methyl peak of triisopropyl silyl-O- as a singlet (may be steric effect cost the dihedral angle close to $90^\circ$?). *JOC* paper even counted 21H for possible 18H (possibly overlapping two signals for each isopropyl 7Hs). I edited my answer accordingly, putting the published spectral values for your convenience.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, and I'm not saying you're wrong, rather I don't know. I've never worked with TIPS groups, only TBS. Since I cannot judge whether the answer is correct or not, I refrain from voting.

Comment: FWIW, for TIPSOH, [*Chem. Lett.* **2014,** *43* (4), 429–431](https://doi.org/10.1246/cl.131079) says δH 1.07 (m, 21 H) and δC 17.7, 12.3. Most other references e.g. [*Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2011,** *50* (33), 7533–7536](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201101993) give similar values, but somewhat intriguingly,  [*Chem. Commun.* **2016,** *52* (70), 10625–10628](https://doi.org/10.1039/C6CC04855B) reports δH 1.43 (s, 21 H) and δC 30.3, 21.1. One wonders if they got the correct product...

Comment: @orthocresol: Good data. I think $\delta$H 1.07 (m, 21 H) and $\delta$C 17.7, 12.3 are more reliable as *Tet Lett* article sited, because the compound I posted should not have interfering peaks at that region. Thanks for the hard work. :-)